# Is it possible to access events of a resource calendar in Google Calendar?

Tags: calendar, google-calendar-api

In the paid version of the Google calendar, there is a feature called resource calendars where calendars can be made for resources like meeting rooms, projectors etc. These can be booked for events by users inside the domain. However, is it possible to get the events list of the resource calendars like how we get it from user calendars using Google calendar API. So far, I have seen the API documentation of resource calendars, and I couldn't find anything of sorts. I would like to know if there is a work around to this?

Comment: Can you provide the links you've checked?

Comment: Directory api - https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/resources/calendars/insert#response

Deprecated Calendar resource API - https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/calendar-resource/#developing_a_naming_strategy_for_your_calendar_resources

Answer (score 2):

As per https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts/domain#domain_resources_and_rooms you can list resources through resources.calendars.list() directory API call: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/resources/calendars/list

Comment: Thanks but i already saw the documentation before posting. I know the resources can be listed but I want to know if it's possible to get the events list of a particular resource. Is there a way for that?

Comment: Yes, of course. You can do calendar API events.list() call with the resource email you retrieved from the directory API. The documentation says:The calendarId corresponds to the resourceEmail field of the Calendar Resource API.

Comment: Now I am facing a another problem, when I share the resource calendar with a service account, the calendar doesn't give it the permission to make changes to the events. What can I do about it? @luc

Comment: Sounds like your domain has maximum calendar sharing ACL limited to read-only. You might need to either make this service account trusted by the domain (through delegation of authority https://developers.google.com/+/domains/authentication/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account) or make the domain restrictions less strict.

Comment: Okay, I gave the service account domain wide delegation and also changed the sharing of calendars to allow being changed by parties outside the domain. It didn't work immediately, but today, I can see that it's working. Maybe it takes a little time for the changes to take effect. Thanks a lot.